# Bind angular mat-checbox ngModule

Tags: angular, checkbox, bind, ng-modules

I have an Array of mat-checbkox, where user can only select one option:

```
export enum ProjectStatus {
  Ready = "Is ready",
  Testing = "is testing",
  Done = "is done"
}

<div *ngFor="let status of projectStatus; let i=index">
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="selected.index === i"
        (change)="selected.index = i; selected.status=status; selected.checked= true;">{{status}}
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Then I got some others mat-checkbox:

```
<div>
    <mat-checkbox>SEND REPORTS</mat-checkbox>
</div>
<div>
    <mat-checkbox>WARN DEVELOPERS</mat-checkbox>
</div>
<div>
    <mat-checkbox>WARN PROJECT MAANGER</mat-checkbox>
</div>
<div>
    <mat-checkbox>WARN TESTERS</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

My question is, how I can check another mat-checkbox dynamically based on the first checkbox list checked. I have to use ngModule?

For example, If I select:

```
is Testing
```

I want to check automatically the checkboxs:

```
SEND REPORTS
WARN DEVELOPERS
```

[image]

That's the link of the testing application:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrnk7t-bxeplb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.html

Answer (score 0):

try using:

I have made changes in you stackblitz, currently it's works as per your condition.You can use **ngModule** or some flags to checked the checkbox

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrnk7t-zrn5x5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.ts